# Can there be a race condition when using case expression (without break statement) in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am seeing a strange unpredictable behaviour in my following Scala code snippet used in authenticated flow :

```
case Some(token) if (token.isValid && !token.isExpired) => {
   // do something
   return Future
}
case Some(token) => {
   // do something
   return Future
}
```

I expected that always only one of the case conditions will be executed but never both. But sometimes I see that both are executed in the order as they appear.
Is it because I am assuming there is no implicit 'break' after each case expression in Scala ? Note that in both case expression I am accessing a DB and returning a Result in Future.

Comment: Add some logging that includes the name of the Thread existing. You will probably find it is two different threads (or more) executing, not one thread executing both.

Comment: Sure. Will do that and will reply back. Don't know how to log Thread ids !!

Comment: Thread.currentThread.getName

Comment: Thanks. I added the logging. Need to wait for the race condition to appear. Unable to reproduce via testing as authentication slow is quite manual and we don't have any automated testing setup for this kind of flow.
Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: To answer your original question, no Scala does not have fall through semantics on case matching.

Comment: Thanks. I referred the book "Programming in Scala, 2 ed", Chapter 7 where it says clearly:
"Another difference is that there are no breaks at the end of each alternative. Instead the break is implicit, and there is no fall through from one alternative to the next. The common case—not falling through—becomes shorter, and a source of errors is avoided because programmers can no longer fall through by accident."
Now I don't understand why did I hit the situation in my code as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Can you make a small self-contained program snippet (i.e. with a `main` method) that reproduces this behaviour? I'd say there's something else going on in your application that looks like both cases are running. If we can see more of your program then we can probably help identify it. There's too little info to debug it at the moment.